# Jinja2 Template get_corresponding_lineno doesn't work

Tags: python, jinja2, template-engine

I would like to build a tool for collecting coverage over Jinja2 template and for that I need to map generated bytecode to source HTML file.

I found a method in `Template` class `get_corresponding_lineno` and it looks like it should do the work, but it doesn't.

Here is my code sample. it contains main script, `main.py` and template file in templates folder, which located in the folder as `main.py`

```
# main.py
import os
import jinja2

TEMPLATE_FILENAME = 'index.html'
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'templates')

env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(TEMPLATE_DIR))

template = env.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILENAME)
text = template.render()
lineno =template.get_corresponding_lineno(1)
```

Template `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if 2 + 2 == 4 %}
    <p>This looks ok</p>
{% else %}
    <p>This is not good</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

When I run main.py I get following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/nikolaygolub/workspace/my/coverage-jinja-plugin/example/run.py", line 15, in <module>
  print(template.get_corresponding_lineno(8))
File "/Users/nikolaygolub/workspace/pyenvs/py3all/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1056, in get_corresponding_lineno
  for template_line, code_line in reversed(self.debug_info):
File "/Users/nikolaygolub/workspace/pyenvs/py3all/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1072, in debug_info
  self._debug_info.split('&')]
File "/Users/nikolaygolub/workspace/pyenvs/py3all/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1071, in <listcomp>
  return [tuple(imap(int, x.split('='))) for x in
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I've explored template object a little bit and found, that `_debug_info` attribute is just empty string.

How could I solve this?

My environment is Python 3.5, Mac OS X, Jinja2 2.8

Similar question: [Jinja, get line of source code after template rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823159/jinja-get-line-of-source-code-after-template-rendering)

**UPD**
I've made a progress. `get_corresponding_lineno` starts working if I add a  `block` to the source:

```
{% block content %}
<body>
{% if 2 + 2 == 4 %}
    <p>This looks ok</p>
{% else %}
    <p>This is not good</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
{% endblock %}
```